# I want to parse like this with values read from a CSV instead of hardcoded value. But I am getting error

Tags: python, parsing, csv

```
#---------------------------------
#THIS IS A PROGRAM TO READ THE INPUT STRING FROM  A CSV
#STORE THE INPUT STRING IN SOME VARIABLE
#PARSE THE INPUT STRING DYNAMICALLY INSTEAD OF HARDCODING

        import csv

        str= "ABCDEFGHIJ"

#print str[4:] --> I want to parse like this with values read from CSV                              

        with open ("abcd.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
        f  =    csv.reader(csvfile)
           for row in f :
               results = row[3]
               intResults = map(int,results) # This is to convert to a integer 
               print str[intResults:]

# ABCD.CSV has 1,2,3,4 as values  in the third column of the rows .
```

Comment: Please show a sample of what the input file looks like, what is your expected output, and what the error looks like.

Comment: error ---> Slice indices must be integers or NONE or __INDEX__ method

Comment: @HaiVu just imagine a CSV file having a fourth column values as 1,3,4,2 in each row. Unfortunately i dont have a way to attach the csv .  But the error its giving is - error ---> Slice indices must be integers or NONE or INDEX

Comment: @Nash_84 don't attach the csv, just take a couple of representative lines and include them in the question. That should be enough. Looking at your code I think it looks like you are trying to use a list as a slice index. print `intResults` before you try to use it to slice `str` and see if it looks liek what you expect. Also `str` is a bad name for your variable as `str` is a built in type.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
result = int(row[2])
```

map(int, '123')  return a list [1,2,3] (slicing needs integers not lists).

An alternate is to use something like:

```
results = map(int,'123')
for i in results:print str[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a slice of the string indexed by the 4th column (index 3) in the csv file. You can just use `int` to convert to integer, you use `map` if you want to convert an iterable (e.g. list).

```
import csv
s= "ABCDEFGHIJ"

with open('nums.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print s[int(row[3]):]
```